# select single node from Xpath query

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm using this code to extract all required nodes from xml:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

    echo "<strong>Using direct method...</strong><br />";
    $items = $xml->xpath('/w:document/w:body/w:tbl/w:tr/w:tc/w:p/w:r/w:t');
    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo "Found $item<br />";
    }
```

I'm getting a long list of entries, but I need possibility to choose any of them seperately. tried to use  `echo "Found $item[2]<br />";` but got error:

> `Warning: main() [function.main]: Cannot add element t number 1 when
>   only 0 such elements exist`thanks for advices

Comment: Wouldn't it be `echo "found $items[2]<br />";` instead of `$item[2]`?

Comment: Great!  I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract the 2nd `w:t` element use the index in xpath instead.

```
$item = list($xml->xpath('(/w:document/w:body/w:tbl/w:tr/w:tc/w:p/w:r/w:t)[3]'));
```

**Note** `3` means 3rd `w:t` element. Xpath Index starts from `1` instead of `0`. And `list` is used to fetch the first element as Xpath always returns an array.

**Also note** this XPath can be reduced to `(//w:r/w:t)[3]`unless same tree is available somewhere else. So it looks like

```
$item = list($xml->xpath('(//w:r/w:t)[3]'));
```

Comment: +1, but does the entire thing need to be in parens like that?

Comment: Yes, For this you need to put parenthesis around the whole xpath query.

Answer (score 2):

it should be `echo "found $items[2]<br />";` instead of `$item[2]`